# Comments are really slow?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments

I'm not sure whether to tag this as a bug or support, but my pc seems to lag excessively when I try to comment on questions or answers.

When I type it takes ages for my text to appear.

Granted that I am using a stone age computer, but this hasn't been a problem before. I'm also not picking this up on stackoverflow.

**Update:**

My pc specs are:

**Browser:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.9) Gecko/20100908 Firefox/3.6.9
```

**System:**

```
Openbox on Archlinux (up-to-date)
1.25 GB RAM
```

**CPU:**

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
model name      : Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 1.80GHz
stepping        : 4
cpu MHz         : 1800.308
cache size      : 512 KB
bogomips        : 3602.64
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 128
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
```

**GPU:**

```
 $ lspci | grep VGA
 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 4000] (rev c1)
```

Comment: odd... no problem here... but my computer is not stone age... browser?

Comment: I've seen this at random on all the SE sites, even trilogy ones; do you get it regularly here and never anywhere else?

Comment: @micheal, I'm only active on SO and Unix SE so I can't comment about other SE sites. And I haven't had any problems elsewhere on the web

Comment: @xeno, latest Firefox, added my specs to the question

Answer (score 2):

This was an issue with css styles changing per keystroke as I recall, and is long since fixed.